# Display the results of mysql_fetch_assoc in a table

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I'm using the function `mysql_fetch_assoc` to return the data in database, but I don't know how to print its result in a table. 
Here is the code that does the process.

```
$number_of_date= "SELECT SUM(number_of_date) AS number_of_date FROM emp_leaves WHERE  emp_id='$userID' AND leave_category='Annual' AND apply_year='$year'";
$res_qry = mysql_query($number_of_date) or die ('Invalid query :: <br/>'.$number_of_date.' <br/>'.mysql_error());

$rowqry = mysql_fetch_assoc($res_qry);
$number_date = $rowqry ['number_of_date'];
<tr>
    <?php while($rowqry = mysql_fetch_assoc($res_qry)) { ?>
        <td><?php echo $rowqry ['number_of_date']?></td>
    <?php } } ?>
</tr>
```

---

It does not work. What is the correct way to display this result ?

Comment: don't use `mysql_fetch_assoc()` twice!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By using `mysql_fetch_assoc()` twice, you assign the first row of result to `$rowqry` already. In your query, you will only have a single row of result because of selecting the `SUM()` of all the results, so that leaves no more results in the `while loop()`.

You can just remove your `while loop()` because it is unnecessary as you will only get a single row.

Also, the fact that your provided code, an HTML entity is inside a PHP. Use `echo`:

```
$number_of_date= "SELECT SUM(number_of_date) AS number_of_date FROM emp_leaves WHERE  emp_id='$userID' AND leave_category='Annual' AND apply_year='$year'";
$res_qry = mysql_query($number_of_date) or die ('Invalid query :: <br/>'.$number_of_date.' <br/>'.mysql_error());

$rowqry = mysql_fetch_assoc($res_qry);
$number_date = $rowqry['number_of_date'];

echo '<tr>
          <td>'.$number_date.'</td>
      </tr>';
```

Note: Use [`mysqli_*`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php) extension instead of deprecated [`mysql_*`](http://php.net/manual/en/migration55.deprecated.php).

Comment: Thank u. Now I fixed the problem by this way.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the first mysql_fetch_assoc()

```
 $number_of_date= "SELECT SUM(number_of_date) AS number_of_date FROM emp_leaves WHERE  emp_id='$userID' AND leave_category='Annual' AND apply_year='$year'";
 $res_qry = mysql_query($number_of_date) or die ('Invalid query :: <br/>'.$number_of_date.' <br/>'.mysql_error());

    <tr>
        <?php while($rowqry = mysql_fetch_assoc($res_qry)) { ?>
            <td><?php echo $rowqry ['number_of_date']?></td>
        <?php } } ?>
    </tr>
```

Comment: Thank u, I fixed the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Your Construct seems to be malformed. Try a different one:

```
    <?php
        $number_of_date = "SELECT SUM(number_of_date) AS number_of_date FROM emp_leaves WHERE  emp_id='$userID' AND leave_category='Annual' AND apply_year='$year'";
        $res_qry        = mysql_query($number_of_date)
        or die ('Invalid query :: <br/>'. $number_of_date . ' <br/>' . mysql_error());

        //$rowqry         = mysql_fetch_assoc($res_qry);    // <== NOT NECESSARY SINCE YOU ARE GOING TO LOOP OVER THE RESULT
        //$number_date    = $rowqry ['number_of_date'];     // <== NOT NECESSARY SINCE YOU ARE GOING TO LOOP OVER THE RESULT

    ?>
    <tr>
        <?php while($rowqry = mysql_fetch_assoc($res_qry)) : ?>
            <td><?php echo $rowqry ['number_of_date']?></td>
         <?php endwhile; ?>
    </tr>
```

Comment: Thank u, I fixed the problem.

Answer (score 1):

actually you have used 2 times `mysql_fetch_assoc` function if you are using inside loop then why are using outside if you are using ones out side loop means you have already fetched one record then cursor move to next record fetch. and if in case in your db there is only one record then in loop you will get nothing because you have already fetched one record outside the loop. in second case if there is more the one record is present in your database then you will get output from second record inside loop due you have use 2 times   `mysql_fetch_assoc`. so please replace your code with below code.

```
$number_of_date = "SELECT SUM(number_of_date) AS number_of_date FROM emp_leaves WHERE  emp_id='$userID' AND leave_category='Annual' AND apply_year='$year'";
$res_qry = mysql_query($number_of_date) or die ('Invalid query :: <br/>'.$number_of_date.' <br/>'.mysql_error());

<tr>
    <?php while($rowqry = mysql_fetch_assoc($res_qry)) { ?>
        <td><?php echo $rowqry ['number_of_date']?></td>
    <?php } } ?>
</tr>
```

try this may your problem will solved.

Comment: Thank u, I fixed the problem.

Answer (score 1):

To begin with, I suggest changing all your mysql_ functions to MySQLi functions. However, for the purpose of your question -> The problem with your code is that you have spaces after the variable of your loop. $res_qry['variable'] is not the same as $res_qry ['variable'].

```
$number_of_date= "SELECT SUM(number_of_date) AS number_of_date FROM emp_leaves WHERE  emp_id='$userID' AND leave_category='Annual' AND apply_year='$year'";
$res_qry = mysql_query($number_of_date) or die ('Invalid query :: <br/>'.$number_of_date.' <br/>'.mysql_error());

<tr>
    <?php while($rowqry = mysql_fetch_assoc($res_qry)) { ?>
        <td><?php echo $rowqry['number_of_date']?></td>
    <?php } } ?>
</tr>
```

Comment: Thank u, I fixed the problem.